# Unable to trigger onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Div element with input and FontIcons as child elements.
When I enter or update any value in the input controller and moves the focus out of that, onBlur event is called.
Here, I also have a click handle on font icon and it is not working as expected.

When I update the input element and click on FantoIcon, Only blur event is triggered but not click event.

How can we trigger click instead of blur event? I tried keeping zIndext but no luck

```html
<div>
    <input onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}>
    <FontIcon onClick ={this.clickHandle}>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`<FontIcon>` is probably not receiving extra `props`. If it's your component, you can add it:

```
export const FontIcon({ propA, propB ...props }) {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      // whatever goes here
    </div>
  );
}
```

If it is not your component, then wrap it in a `<button>` or `div` with role=button:

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandle}>
  <FontIcon />
</button
```

Comment: I agree but when we move focus out, it is triggering onBlur() and not triggering click() event. Because, clicking button/font icon also, it is also focus out event so onBlur() method is being called

Comment: When a 'blur' event occurs, how can we find out which element focus went *to*?